# How to set alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Can any body tell me how to set the alarm? I have one time picker but every time when I kill  my application time is also updating with current system time.

Comment: what do you mean by killing your application? Maybe the timepicker is initiated with the system time when you open it? Check the TimePickerDialog constructor for hour and minutes value.

Comment: Try posting the code where you are setting your alarm. It will be easier to suggest what you could do. The question is not quite clear without it.

Comment: Bogdan M i mean closing application and opening again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for that. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html) for an example.

The example in the docs (link above) should be sufficient. Use [sql.Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) to get the actual date from the sql and convert it to milliseconds to set the alarm.

Comment: An example from the API demos: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html

Comment: hey dude really i am not able to understand that.

Comment: which part, show us what you have and we'll help you from there.

Comment: in that alarm manager example where there are setting their own time for alarm.

Comment: Look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Answer (score 2):

Try the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class.